# require_once: failed to open stream: Permission denied(lampp)

Tags: php, permissions, lampp

I need help solving , what says to be a permission error in the `htdocs` folder, because i needed to alter them to even add folders in the first place.

This is my `init.php` file:

```
<?php
//Start Session
session_start();

//Include Configuration
require_once('config/config.php');

//Helper Function Files
require_once('helpers/system_helper.php');
require_once('helpers/format_helper.php');
require_once('helpers/db_helper.php');

//Autoload Classes
function __autoload($class_name){
require_once('libraries/'.$class_name . '.php');
}
?>
```

I try to include it via `

When i run my `index.php` file i get this error:

```
Warning: require_once(../../htdocs/PHP-Wizard/helpers/system_helper.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /opt/lampp/htdocs/PHP-Wizard/core/init.php on line 9

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '../../htdocs/PHP-Wizard/helpers/system_helper.php' (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/PHP-Wizard/core/init.php on line 9
```

I tried going one folder up with `../` , but it doesn't work.

I looked around for a similar error to mine, but no luck. They all say `No such file or directory in (path)`.

Could it be that it is the same error, or do i really need to change my permissions, if so, how can i do that?

Edit: When i use `include_once('helpers/system_helper.php');` i get this error:

```
Warning: include_once(helpers/system_helper.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /opt/lampp/htdocs/PHP-Wizard/core/init.php on line 9

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'helpers/system_helper.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/PHP-Wizard/core/init.php on line 9

Warning: include_once(helpers/format_helper.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /opt/lampp/htdocs/PHP-Wizard/core/init.php on line 10

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'helpers/format_helper.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/PHP-Wizard/core/init.php on line 10

Warning: include_once(helpers/db_helper.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /opt/lampp/htdocs/PHP-Wizard/core/init.php on line 11

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'helpers/db_helper.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/PHP-Wizard/core/init.php on line 11
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was indeed the permissions, i'm guessing because i copied the folder.

I fixed it by `chmod 777` on all the files in that folder, and now it works fine.

Thank you for your time attempting to help me.

Comment: That is simply a REALLY BAD idea.

Comment: Better change the user and group ownership to the appropriate one by "sudo chown". If you use an apache server with linux you can find the answer of what is the right user and group in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf and /etc/apache2/envvars.

Answer (score 1):

I tested using relative paths and it works fine.

```
<?php

require_once '../test.php';

echo ' you';
```

Where `test.php` just contains `echo "hello";` resulted in the expected "hello you".

I would guess your problem is with file permissions. Can you check what permissions are on your `system_helper.php`? It should be at least executable by the user php is running as (usually www-data). I could reproduce your error message by doing a `chown root test.php` and `chmod 600 test.php` so I would guess something like

`chown www-data: system_helper.php`

or

`chmod g+rwx system_helper.php`

should give you permission to run the script.

Comment: this is what it says when i type "ls -ld /opt/lampp/htdocs"

drwxrwsrwx 6 root www 4096 Nov 16 23:18 /opt/lampp/htdocs

Comment: and this is what it says when i type "ls -ld /opt/lampp/htdocs/PHP-Wizard"
--drwxr-xr-x 12 xy www 4096 Nov 25 21:34 /opt/lampp/htdocs/PHP-Wizard/

Comment: these are my permission for system-helper.php:-rw------- 1 xy xy 1518

Comment: I think you could look into [file permissions](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/309527-understanding-linux-file-permissions) but for now if this is just a test project that won't be live it should be safe to run `sudo chmod a+rwx <filename-here>` on all your project files. `chmod` is for changing file permissions. `a+rwx` means allow `a`ll users to `r`ead, `w`rite and e`x`ecute this file. You can see from your system-helper permissions that only the file owner has read and write permissions. If php is running as a different user then it won't be able to access this file.